# Could anyone help me to know how to make this to work?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to output data in the different  tag on call but nothing seems to work, I really dont know what i am doing wrong, could anyone help me?
it displays "Illegal string offset 'patient' in" in all the 
PS: I am a beginner to php and mysql. I have edited my code and figured out some errors and I have now noticed that the error is thrown at line 73 on my foreach loop "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

```
<?php include"../Include/header.php";?>
<?php include"../Include/sidebar.php";?>
<?php
include("../inc/connect.php") ;

$db_connect =mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","clinic_management");
$s="SELECT * FROM addappointment WHERE `app_date` = '".date('Y-m-d')."'";
$query=mysqli_query($db_connect, $s)or die (mysql_error($db_connect));

$row1=mysql_fetch_all($query);
function mysql_fetch_all($query) 
{
  $temp='';
$all = array();
while ($all[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {$temp=$all;}
return $temp;
// print_r($numrows);echo "string"; exit();
}
?>

<div class="content-wrapper">
<section class="content-header">
<h1>
Today's Appointment
<small></small>
</h1>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
<li class="active">Today's Appointment
</li>
</ol>
</section>
<section class="content">
<!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="box box-primary">
<div class="box-header with-border">
<i class="fa fa-user"></i> <h3 class="box-title">  Today's Appointment</h3>
</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="./addappointment.php"><button type="submit"   name="submit" class="btn btn-success bg-blue"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add Appointment</button></a><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<!--    <td>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Copy</button>
</td> -->
<td>
<a href="./Exceltoday.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Excel</button></a>
</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
<a href="./csvtoday.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">CSV</button></a>
</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
<a href="./PDF/today_pdf.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">PDF</button></a>
</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
<button type="button" onclick="window.print();" class="btn btn-default">Print</button>
</td>
<div class="box-body">
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> id </th>
<th> Patient </th>
<th> Date </th>
<th> Start Time </th>
<th> End Time </th>
<th> Remark </th>
<th> Option </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach($row1 as $row)
{ 
$sql1=" SELECT name FROM patientregister WHERE id='".$row['patient']."'";
$write1 =mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($db_connect));
//print_r($sql); exit;
$row2=mysqli_fetch_array($write1)or die (mysqli_error($db_connect));
//print_r($row2); echo $row2['name']; exit;
//echo "$description"; exit();
//print_r($row1); exit;
//echo "$description"; exit();


?> <tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['app_date'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['starttime'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['endtime'];?></td> 
<td><?php echo $row['remark'];?></td>
<td><a href="deletet.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><span class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</span></a></td> 
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
<?php include "../Include/footer.php";?>
```

Comment: Which line cuases that problem?

Comment: I would like to output data in the tbody especially in the <td> but nothing seems to work

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Until which line does everything work fine?

Comment: it has now said that the line of the foreach ($row1 as $row) is invalid and then throws this warning msg "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid"? Is there any error message given you want to share? Please do so by editing the question. Also, please share all attempts to resolve the problem - for example, what does `$row1` contain?

Answer (score 0):

If the query doesn't return any rows, `mysql_fetch_all()` will return an empty string instead of an empty array, because you initialize `$temp` to a string.

There's no need for the `$temp` variable in the first place, you can just return `$all`.

```
function mysql_fetch_all($query) 
{
    $all = array();
    while ($all[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {}
    return $all;
}
```

Also, if you have the `MSYQLND` driver, there's a built-in `mysqli_fetch_all()` function, you don't need to write your own.